# How to sort a String array in alphabetical order without using compareTo?

Tags: java

I’m trying to sort through a String array of names. I have two different string arrays for first names and last names and I’m trying to sort through them in alphabetical order without using any kind of array sorting. Is there any kind of way to tell Java whether we want our String array going from increasing to decreasing order?

Comment: What is wrong with using CompareTo?

Comment: The [`Comparator.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method is not named `compareTo`. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Generally classes extend `Comparable` and implement `compareTo` in order to designate a natural order for their objects. However you could write your own `Comparator<String>` that performs a custom ordering.

```
Comparator<String> myOrder (s1, s2) -> ... calculate order ...
Arrays.sort(stringArray, myOrder);
```

Once you've defined a `Comparator` you can reverse it with `.reversed()` which would make you sort in descending rather than ascending order:

```
Arrays.sort(stringArray, myOrder.reversed());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> [Arrays.sort()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-sort-a-String-array-in-Java)

Which would look like:

> Arrays.sort(arrayName);

This is for increasing order, i case you want to change it to decresing modify the code to

> Arrays.sort(arrayName, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: That uses `String.compareTo`